# Ubuntu very slow despite high specs PC

Tags: boot, performance

I have received a PC 2 days ago and I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, however, the system feels pretty slow given the PC specs. Settings take around a second to load, Firefox more, etc... Here are my specs:

1TB SSD (NVME), the disk utility benchmark showed 3.1 GB/s read speed. Moreover I have only filled around 5% of the disk.

CPU: Intel® Core™ i9-9900 CPU @ 3.10GHz

RAM: 32 GBs with speed of 2667 MT/s

I have it set to high performance and power usage. I have used another PC with lower specs (and HDD) which had slower load speeds.

If it matters, the PC had Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed (dual boot), I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu and indicated to erase everything.
I am not sure where to proceed from here, any help would be appreciated. I can run any requested benchmarks.

[image]

7zip benchmark gives the following:

[image]

The command `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 5` gives the following output:

```
turbostat version 2022.04.16 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
CPUID(0): GenuineIntel 0x16 CPUID levels
CPUID(1): family:model:stepping 0x6:9e:d (6:158:13) microcode 0xf4
CPUID(0x80000000): max_extended_levels: 0x80000008
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR SMX EIST TM2 TSC MSR ACPI-TM HT TM
CPUID(6): APERF, TURBO, DTS, PTM, HWP, HWPnotify, HWPwindow, HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, EPB
cpu4: MSR_IA32_MISC_ENABLE: 0x00850089 (TCC EIST MWAIT PREFETCH TURBO)
CPUID(7): SGX
cpu4: MSR_IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00060005 (Locked SGX)
CPUID(0x15): eax_crystal: 2 ebx_tsc: 258 ecx_crystal_hz: 0
TSC: 3096 MHz (24000000 Hz * 258 / 2 / 1000000)
CPUID(0x16): base_mhz: 3100 max_mhz: 5000 bus_mhz: 100
cpu4: MSR_MISC_PWR_MGMT: 0x00401cc0 (ENable-EIST_Coordination DISable-EPB DISable-OOB)
RAPL: 4033 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 65 Watts
cpu4: MSR_PLATFORM_INFO: 0x8080838f1011f00
8 * 100.0 = 800.0 MHz max efficiency frequency
31 * 100.0 = 3100.0 MHz base frequency
cpu4: MSR_IA32_POWER_CTL: 0x002c005d (C1E auto-promotion: DISabled)
cpu4: MSR_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x2e2f2f3030313232
46 * 100.0 = 4600.0 MHz max turbo 8 active cores
47 * 100.0 = 4700.0 MHz max turbo 7 active cores
47 * 100.0 = 4700.0 MHz max turbo 6 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 5 active cores
48 * 100.0 = 4800.0 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
49 * 100.0 = 4900.0 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
50 * 100.0 = 5000.0 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
50 * 100.0 = 5000.0 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
cpu4: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_NOMINAL: 0x0000001f (base_ratio=31)
cpu4: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_1: 0x00000000 ()
cpu4: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_LEVEL_2: 0x00000000 ()
cpu4: MSR_CONFIG_TDP_CONTROL: 0x80000000 ( lock=1)
cpu4: MSR_TURBO_ACTIVATION_RATIO: 0x00000000 (MAX_NON_TURBO_RATIO=0 lock=0)
cpu4: MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL: 0x1e008006 (UNdemote-C3, UNdemote-C1, demote-C3, demote-C1, locked, pkg-cstate-limit=6 (pc8))
/dev/cpu_dma_latency: 2000000000 usec (default)
current_driver: intel_idle
current_governor: menu
current_governor_ro: menu
cpu4: POLL: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
cpu4: C1: MWAIT 0x00
cpu4: C1E: MWAIT 0x01
cpu4: C3: MWAIT 0x10
cpu4: C6: MWAIT 0x20
cpu4: C7s: MWAIT 0x33
cpu4: C8: MWAIT 0x40
cpu4: C9: MWAIT 0x50
cpu4: C10: MWAIT 0x60
cpu4: cpufreq driver: intel_pstate
cpu4: cpufreq governor: powersave
cpufreq intel_pstate no_turbo: 0
cpu4: MSR_MISC_FEATURE_CONTROL: 0x00000000 (L2-Prefetch L2-Prefetch-pair L1-Prefetch L1-IP-Prefetch)
cpu0: MSR_PM_ENABLE: 0x00000001 (HWP)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_CAPABILITIES: 0x01081f32 (high 50 guar 31 eff 8 low 1)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_REQUEST: 0x00003208 (min 8 max 50 des 0 epp 0x0 window 0x0 pkg 0x0)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_INTERRUPT: 0x00000001 (EN_Guaranteed_Perf_Change, Dis_Excursion_Min)
cpu0: MSR_HWP_STATUS: 0x00000000 (No-Guaranteed_Perf_Change, No-Excursion_Min)
cpu0: EPB: 6 (balanced)
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT: 0x000a0e03 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000061 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_INFO: 0x00000208 (65 W TDP, RAPL 0 - 0 W, 0.000000 sec.)
cpu0: MSR_PKG_POWER_LIMIT: 0x4284b000dd8208 (UNlocked)
cpu0: PKG Limit #1: ENabled (65.000 Watts, 28.000000 sec, clamp ENabled)
cpu0: PKG Limit #2: ENabled (150.000 Watts, 0.002441* sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_VR_CURRENT_CONFIG: 0x00000850
cpu0: PKG Limit #4: 266.000000 Watts (UNlocked)
cpu0: MSR_DRAM_POWER_LIMIT: 0x5400de00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: DRAM Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP0_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: Cores Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POLICY: 0
cpu0: MSR_PP1_POWER_LIMIT: 0x00000000 (UNlocked)
cpu0: GFX Limit: DISabled (0.000 Watts, 0.000977 sec, clamp DISabled)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_TEMPERATURE_TARGET: 0x00640e00 (100 C) (100 default - 0 offset)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_STATUS: 0x88430000 (33 C)
cpu0: MSR_IA32_PACKAGE_THERM_INTERRUPT: 0x00000003 (100 C, 100 C)
cpu4: MSR_PKGC3_IRTL: 0x0000884e (valid, 79872 ns)
cpu4: MSR_PKGC6_IRTL: 0x00008876 (valid, 120832 ns)
cpu4: MSR_PKGC7_IRTL: 0x00008894 (valid, 151552 ns)
cpu4: MSR_PKGC8_IRTL: 0x000088fa (valid, 256000 ns)
cpu4: MSR_PKGC9_IRTL: 0x0000894c (valid, 339968 ns)
cpu4: MSR_PKGC10_IRTL: 0x00008bf2 (valid, 1034240 ns)
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
2.94    4763    15329   32  17.78   14.33   0.00    1.24
4.69    4818    10890   58  24.93   21.41   0.00    1.25
5.57    4829    7448    56  30.74   27.28   0.00    1.16
7.75    4754    18042   58  36.45   32.87   0.00    1.26
2.63    4782    11306   33  19.02   15.54   0.00    1.23
0.91    4806    4990    33  7.23    3.97    0.00    1.21
0.88    4812    4102    34  9.98    6.74    0.00    1.19
1.15    4822    4733    35  8.76    5.50    0.00    1.21
0.77    4771    3653    32  7.42    4.18    0.00    1.20
0.34    4819    1958    32  5.18    2.01    0.00    1.15
0.91    4800    3944    33  9.83    6.58    0.00    1.19
0.99    4814    3628    34  7.45    4.20    0.00    1.22
0.82    4848    2831    31  6.65    3.43    0.00    1.19
0.98    4810    3599    31  7.29    4.05    0.00    1.22
0.97    4837    4086    32  9.51    6.24    0.00    1.20
0.74    4808    3381    31  8.29    5.06    0.00    1.19
1.15    4809    5997    31  9.03    5.77    0.00    1.21
0.37    4833    2467    31  5.44    2.26    0.00    1.16
0.52    4805    3107    31  6.12    2.91    0.00    1.17
0.52    4804    2950    31  6.16    2.97    0.00    1.17
0.21    4821    1675    31  4.43    1.27    0.00    1.14
0.20    4858    1041    30  4.11    0.98    0.00    1.12
0.40    4807    2093    31  5.14    1.98    0.00    1.15
0.27    4840    1772    30  4.66    1.48    0.00    1.14
0.14    4820    1119    31  3.93    0.80    0.00    1.13
0.23    4866    1078    30  4.16    1.01    0.00    1.13
0.20    4753    1308    30  4.20    1.05    0.00    1.13
0.11    4881    956 30  3.82    0.70    0.00    1.13
0.13    4840    1317    30  4.14    1.00    0.00    1.13
0.11    4896    1056    29  3.86    0.74    0.00    1.13
0.41    4822    2039    30  5.08    1.93    0.00    1.14
0.06    4887    760 29  3.60    0.48    0.00    1.12
0.40    4842    2283    30  5.04    1.89    0.00    1.15
1.47    4892    2640    49  10.81   7.62    0.00    1.18
sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 5
0.29    4795    1590    32  4.72    1.58    0.00    1.13
0.14    4820    1353    30  4.14    0.97    0.00    1.13
0.22    4853    1138    29  4.23    1.09    0.00    1.13
0.07    4894    822 29  3.64    0.52    0.00    1.12
0.42    4818    2593    30  5.34    2.18    0.00    1.16
0.16    4835    1191    29  4.14    1.01    0.00    1.13
0.20    4801    2459    29  4.31    1.17    0.00    1.13
0.22    4866    1146    29  4.16    1.02    0.00    1.13
0.18    4765    1230    29  4.10    0.96    0.00    1.13
0.08    4889    919 29  3.73    0.59    0.00    1.12
0.09    4881    878 29  3.72    0.58    0.00    1.12
0.19    4872    993 29  4.02    0.89    0.00    1.12
0.17    4753    1111    29  3.96    0.84    0.00    1.13
0.08    4886    894 29  3.72    0.59    0.00    1.12
0.06    4885    787 29  3.60    0.48    0.00    1.12
0.19    4887    982 29  4.04    0.91    0.00    1.12
0.18    4773    1244    29  4.02    0.89    0.00    1.13
0.10    4864    950 29  3.80    0.65    0.00    1.13
0.10    4852    954 29  3.78    0.65    0.00    1.12
0.09    4834    970 29  3.81    0.68    0.00    1.12
0.27    4785    1618    28  4.39    1.24    0.00    1.13
0.08    4877    868 28  3.69    0.56    0.00    1.12
0.08    4889    874 29  3.69    0.57    0.00    1.12
0.08    4838    872 28  3.68    0.56    0.00    1.12
0.28    4780    1500    29  4.29    1.15    0.00    1.13
0.12    4715    1113    29  3.99    0.86    0.00    1.13
0.67    4844    3047    29  6.75    3.53    0.00    1.19
1.59    4700    5280    30  8.96    5.62    0.00    1.19
29.97   4625    40322   54  73.12   69.27   0.00    2.15
11.21   4713    12435   34  38.98   35.46   0.00    1.53
3.41    4729    7224    33  15.85   12.54   0.00    1.27
2.83    4782    5703    32  13.07   10.45   0.00    1.25
3.59    4722    6757    33  14.14   11.70   0.00    1.29
12.13   4634    13940   34  33.62   30.14   0.00    1.50
5.04    4727    6146    33  19.55   16.21   0.00    1.24
0.50    4869    1506    33  5.69    2.51    0.00    1.14
0.63    4821    1816    33  6.10    2.94    0.00    1.14
0.27    4863    1281    32  4.62    1.47    0.00    1.14
0.32    4867    1281    31  4.87    1.72    0.00    1.14
0.59    4752    1922    32  5.50    2.33    0.00    1.14
0.57    4817    1722    31  5.77    2.59    0.00    1.14
0.42    4853    1399    31  5.40    2.24    0.00    1.14
2.36    4678    3785    31  10.17   6.95    0.00    1.20
0.33    4836    1693    31  4.98    1.80    0.00    1.14
0.53    4805    2628    31  6.03    2.82    0.00    1.17
0.55    4815    3085    32  6.09    2.87    0.00    1.18
0.49    4794    3314    31  6.09    2.89    0.00    1.17
1.10    4830    5232    31  8.33    5.02    0.00    1.22
0.62    4788    3419    31  6.80    3.58    0.00    1.18
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body f the question. This makes it easier to read, can be searched and nothing gets cut off.

Comment: Is your computer throttling due to processor temperature and/or power limits? As always, I recommend the use of turbostat (linux-tools-common package, I think) to investigate. Try this: `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 5` as you experiment with various CPU loads.

Comment: I ran the command for few minutes and edited the post with the output @DougSmythies

Comment: Your turbostat output all looks fine. There wasn't much CPU load, so it didn't really reveal what happens to processor temperature under high load. There was one sample at 73 watts and only 53 degrees, so it looks good. If sustained the 73 watts could eventually throttle to 65 watts.